# How to move values ​from one array to another in angular 11

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to move a value on one array to another. Here's the first array

```
"availableMember": [
      {
        "id": 18,
        "userDivisionId": 1,
        "userDivisionCode": "1",
        "userDivisionName": "DEPT. MARKETING & LOGISTIK"
      },
      {
        "id": 26,
        "userDivisionId": 333,
        "userDivisionCode": "2.3.21.02",
        "userDivisionName": "YGY PO"
      },
      {
        "id": 27,
        "userDivisionId": 335,
        "userDivisionCode": "2.3.21.02.04",
        "userDivisionName": "YGY MO"
      },
    ]
```

and I want to move, for example object with `userDivisionId` is 333, to the second array.

```
"selectedMember": []
```

I already try using `.splice()`, but sometimes its work and sometimes it doesn't. Any idea how to do this? Please help me.
Thank you.

Comment: Do you also know the key used for filtering.. for example, in your case above it is userDivisionId. Do you know it before hand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array.find()` is the most appropriate method. It takes a function as a parameter and will return the **first** element in which the function returns `true`. If you want to find **all** occurrences, just substitute `find` with `filter`. Use `Array.push()` to add an element to an array, or `Array.concat()` to concatenate two arrays.

```js
 availableMember = [
    {
      id: 18,
      userDivisionId: 1,
      userDivisionCode: '1',
      userDivisionName: 'DEPT. MARKETING & LOGISTIK',
    },
    {
      id: 26,
      userDivisionId: 333,
      userDivisionCode: '2.3.21.02',
      userDivisionName: 'YGY PO',
    },
    {
      id: 27,
      userDivisionId: 335,
      userDivisionCode: '2.3.21.02.04',
      userDivisionName: 'YGY MO',
    },
  ];
  selectedMember: any[] = [];
```

**Adding a single element**

```js
  ngOnInit(): void {
    const selected = this.availableMember.find(
      (el) => el.userDivisionId === 333
    );
    this.selectedMember.push(selected);
  }
```

**Adding multiple elements**

```js
  ngOnInit(): void {
    const selected = this.availableMember.filter(
      (el) => el.userDivisionId === 333 || el.userDivisionId === 335
    );
    this.selectedMember = this.selectedMember.concat(selected);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like below, where you can pass division id into the `function` call like `selectMember(333)`. This is a dynamic approach. You can also transform or overload this function with more inputs to match `userDivisionName` or `id` in future

```
const selectMember = (divisionId) => {
  availableMember.map(function(x) {
    if (x.userDivisionId === divisionId)
      selectedMember.push(x)
  })
}
```

or variation of the above function

```
const selectMemberV2= (divisionId) => {
  selectedMember = availableMember.filter(x => x.userDivisionId === divisionId);
}
```

---

Working Code

```js
let availableMember = [{
    "id": 18,
    "userDivisionId": 1,
    "userDivisionCode": "1",
    "userDivisionName": "DEPT. MARKETING & LOGISTIK"
  },
  {
    "id": 26,
    "userDivisionId": 333,
    "userDivisionCode": "2.3.21.02",
    "userDivisionName": "YGY PO"
  },
  {
    "id": 27,
    "userDivisionId": 335,
    "userDivisionCode": "2.3.21.02.04",
    "userDivisionName": "YGY MO"
  },
];


selectedMember = [];
// function to select member with different input
const selectMember = (divisionId) => {
  availableMember.map(function(x) {
    if (x.userDivisionId === divisionId)
      selectedMember.push(x)
  })
}

// call 
selectMember(333);

//log
console.log(selectedMember)
```

Comment: you could try using filter method instead of using map and a if statement

Comment: I can yes, and there can be more ways, but this came while I was answering :)